# How to superseed Glassfish's built-in libraries with dependencies shipped in EAR?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

GlassFish 4.1 provides EclipseLink 2.5.x in `glassfish/modules`. I want to use 2.6.4 in my application and am including it when packaging it with `maven-ear-plugin:2.10.1` with

```
<configuration>
    <finalName>linuxtracker2</finalName>
    <version>7</version>
    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
</configuration>
```

and the EJB and WAR module as dependency (and default values otherwise). The application deploys and works fine, but I suspect that EclipseLink 2.5 has an issue and I want to overwrite it anyway because I don't want to (double) configure the server to provide dependencies.

I figured out so far that [GlassFish has a classloader hierarchy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7695/6niugesfp/index.html#indexterm-28) and that load requests are delegated to the topmost parent which can satisfy it, but the docs fail of course to explain how to use that. There's [Circumventing Class Loader Isolation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7695/beadh/index.html) which I'd say from my understanding does the opposite of what I want to acchieve (isolate the class loader to use my packaged dependencies).

My application setup is the standard: entity classes and EJB interfaces, EJB implemetations, web frontend and EAR maven module.

Related troubles:

- Glassfish 4 documentation is hard to find via google, search terms with "glassfish 4" return results for 3.x only, I didn't manage
- the Oracle documentation database http://docs.oracle.com doesn't provide documentation for GlassFish 4.x - that's low, even for Oracle
- links in the 3.x documentation - why not try it since I have unlimited time - include dead links like http://blogs.sun.com/sivakumart/entry/classloaders_in_glassfish_an_attempt on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7695/gatej/index.html
- WildFly has a quite cryptic feedback which is only targeting core developer judging from its form and the possility to understand it (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090661/how-to-figure-out-what-missing-service-dependencies-in-wildfly-10-mean for example); afaik it's the only other FLOSS Java EE application server which is Java EE 7 certified
- I can't user GlassFish 4.1.1 because of https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21437.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GlassFish is no longer supported by Oracle, and therefore just an open source project now. The documentation can be found at https://glassfish.java.net/documentation.html - you will need to download the "Administration Guide" PDF, though the others are quite useful too.

What you're trying to do here isn't possible in GlassFish, but is a feature added to Payara Server, which is derived from GlassFish (**disclaimer:** I work for them).

For EAR files, Payara Server has added the option to add `<classloading-delegate>false</classloading-delegate>` in your `META-INF/glassfish-application.xml` file. This should stop your application using libraries from Payara Server when you have your own versions packaged in your EAR.

For your specific use-case, though, you would not need to use this since [Payara Server already comes with EclipseLink 2.6.4](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/master/appserver/pom.xml#L124) in the [latest build, 171.1](http://www.payara.fish/downloads)

Comment: Awesome, best news in weeks! I'll test it as soon as https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1500 has been closed (you're already on it, so even better) and accept. Thank you!